# How can I filter entries based on occurrence count?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Using the stream API, how can I filter after collecting using a `groupingBy`->`counting` operation contain entries based on a filter of the number of occurrences?

Given the following:

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = Stream.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
        .collect(groupingBy(n -> n, counting()));
```

How do I filter this to only contain keys `2` and `5`?

I could use the following, but I was hoping for something that would be able to continue with the stream instead of needing to collect first.

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = Stream.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
        .collect(groupingBy(n -> n, counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(n -> n.getValue() > 1)
        .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way around building a map or similar data structure for an operation that depends on already-seen values. That’s the same with, e.g., `distinct` which looks like a step within the chain of operations but can’t work without building a map (or map-like structure) internally.

You can make the entire thing look like a single stream operation using

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = Stream.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
    .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(n -> n, counting()),
       map -> map.entrySet().stream()
         .filter(n -> n.getValue() > 1)
         .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
    ));
```

but that won’t change the way it works. Keep in mind that every encountered value must be remembered first, as it requires reaching the end of the stream to deduce that no other occurrence of the value exists.

Note that sometimes a non-stream operation may look more concise:

```
Map<Integer, Long> counts = Stream.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
    .collect(groupingBy(n -> n, HashMap::new, counting()));
counts.values().removeIf(count -> count < 2);
```

---

If you are interested in processing the items itself within a (parallel capable) `Stream` without caring about the actual number of occurrences, here is a simple solution:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Integer> counts=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Stream.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
      .filter(i -> counts.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum)==2)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It allows applying the follow-up operations up to the terminal operation as soon as a second item of a kind has been encountered without the need process all items or to wait for the end of the stream and harmonizes with `parallel` execution and/or short-circuiting operations like `limit` or `findAny`, etc.

Comment: the point being that distinct works on parallel, I'm sure a spliterator could be provided that keeps a count of occurrences accepting the first that satisfies a functional (for a greater than example). The spliterator would need arguments to control if all for same must be visited before accepting the count. If the stream is sorted each accept will occur sooner passing the object further in the stream pipeline.

Comment: That’s way beyond the scope of your question as written. Your stream hasn’t a *sorted* property and the operation as shown in your question will not benefit in any way from such complicated implementation as you are collecting the result into a map from number to count of occurrences, which requires processing each item anyway.

Comment: Simple example, maybe I shouldn't have collected to map, I was using that to highlight what I was trying to achieve, what the eventual result is doesn't matter, the spliterator doesn't require the upstream to be sorted, was just highlighting it could benefit. It seems there's nothing available, I may attempt a spliterator implementation to process as I described.

Comment: Maybe my update is closer to what you wanted to achieve in the first place.

Comment: There we go, that's what I was looking for :) I was also attempting to write a stream implementation that could take a predicate to allow for an op on the count, but all the useful classes in the stream API are private, makes it a little more challenging. Thanks Holger.